# Construct such function, that can't be integrated on an interval, but its square is integrable on the interval

Tags: calculus, integration

Okay, so there's the text of my problem on Russian:
 Построить не интегрируемую функцию на отрезке, квадрат которой
интегрируем на этом отрезке.
And its translation on English:
Construct such function, that can't be integrated on an interval, but its square is integrable on the interval.
So I decided to start with the $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^p}$, that doesn't converge with $p > 1$ and does vice versa on a segment $[0,1]$ but I found nothing out, because my $p$ has to be $> 1$, and thus $p^2$ is also $> 1$.
Then I tried to do something with the square root on some negative interval(e.g. $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5-x^2}}$ on an $[-8,-2]$ interval. By this way, it makes some sense kinda. But I want to know, is there some other functions that can't be integrated, but its square is integrable.
Well, I forgot to say, the interval is closed one.

Comment: Which integral are you using? If Riemann, try something based on the indicator of the rationals, on $[0,1]$. E.g., $f(x) = 2\mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)-1$. Note that $f(x)\in\{-1,1\}$ for every $x\in[0,1]$, so $f(x)^2 = 1$.

Comment: Yes, it's Riemann integral. 
Do you mean Dirichlet function? Well, I kinda was thinking about this, and it kinda should be a solution for its problem. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what the name Dirichlet function refers to: I am literally talking about the function given in my comment, where $1_{\mathbb Q}$ is the function which takes value 1 on the rationals and 0 on the irrationals.

Comment: Ye, okay, gotcha, we're talking about one function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're allowed to use an unbounded interval, then $\frac1x$ on $[1,\infty)$ works. In any bounded interval, a good choice is a function that equals either $1$ or $-1$, depending whether $x$ is rational or irrational, or something like that. This was suggested in the comments by Clement C., who wrote it out as the formula $f(x)=2\mathbf{1}_{\Bbb Q}-1$.

Concerning your example, which is equivalent to integrating $\frac1{\sqrt x}$ on any interval of negative numbers, that feels like it works for the wrong reason somehow. We'd like to see $f(x)$ defined, but not integrable, as opposed to not being integrable because it's not even defined.

What I'm not finding right now is an example of a continuous function on a bounded interval that is not integrable, whose square is integrable on that bounded interval. If such an example cannot be produced, there must be a reason.....

Comment: A continuous function on a compact interval is always Riemann integrable. However, this fails on intervals which are not closed: consider $1/x$ on $(0, 1]$, for instance.

Comment: Yes, and this is why I felt like something wrong with the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, so probably the only option is the indicator function of the rational numbers kinda

Comment: @Qeeko, yes, you're correct. That's why I said "bounded" instead of "closed and bounded". That doesn't answer the question I'm bringing up, though. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: If you want to add the example from the comments to your answer, by all means go ahead.

Comment: @ClementC. It's already fully described in my answer. I was just giving credit to you, because you said it before I did. Do you think it would improve the answer to write out the formula instead of a piecewise description?

Comment: Not sure. But since comments are not guaranteed to last, if a moderator or the system cleans up and this disappears the reference to the comments may look puzzling :)

Comment: Fair point. Making an edit now. :)

Comment: @Qeeko, as far as Riemann integration, I see your point. I'm curious about an improper Riemann integral that might satisfy the conditions that $\int f\,\,dx$ diverges, while $\int f^2\,\,dx$ converges, or else a proof that such is impossible. Yes, I realize I'm speaking beyond the scope of the current question.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs I don't know about such a function at the moment, but it would at least have to be unbounded. For consider the case that $a < b$ and that $f \colon (a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and bounded. Then $f$ extends to a bounded function on $[a, b]$ whose only discontinuity is at $a$. This extension must therefore be Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$, hence $f$ must possess an improper Riemann integral on $(a, b]$.

Comment: @Qeeko Yes, that's good.... It seems that, if the function is unbounded, then squaring it would make it "worse" in the sense needed to have an improper integral converge. Not sure how to make that idea precise, though.....

Comment: @GTonyJacobs I think I have managed to make it precise. Again, suppose $a < b$, but let $f \colon (a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and unbounded. Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $\int_a^b f$ diverges while $\int_a^b f^2$ converges. First, pick $a < c < b$ such that $|f| \ge 1$ on $(a, c]$. Then $f^2 \ge |f|$ on $(a, c]$, and since $\int_a^c f^2$ converges, so must $\int_a^c |f|$, a contradiction.

Comment: Nice! That seems to work! :)

Comment: Indeed, but the proof should be cleaned up a bit: a direct proof of convergence of $\int_a^b f^2$ implying convergence of $\int_a^b f$ would be less convoluted…

Comment: @Qeeko Such a $c$ need not exist. The proof follows that idea on the set $\{|f|>1\}$, only that that set doesn't have to contain a whole interval of the form $(a,c]$.

Comment: @fishroe Indeed, well spotted. Don't know what I was thinking… It seems that the function $f \colon (0, 1) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = g \bigl( \tan(\pi(x - 1/2)) \bigr)$, where $g(u) = u \sin(u)$, can be used to construct a counterexample of the kind you mention.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int^\infty_1 \frac1{x^{2/3}}dx$$ diverges by p-test.

$$\int^\infty_1 \frac1{x^{4/3}}dx$$ converges by p-test.